# marshal/unmarshal a java method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb, xml-serialization, jax-ws

I have a java class that contain a method with some logic control . This class is avaible as output via a webservice method to a java swing client .

My question sounds crazy but is it possible to marshal/unmarshal the method to make it available  to the client when he generate the class from the wsdl file ?

Thanks.

ps:I'm using Metro/jax-ws and glassfish 3.1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean so you can send some logic down to the client to be executed there?
I'm afraid the answer is no - this is not how web services work.
All the logic is performed on the server side.

Why do you wish to do this?

Comment: The application I'm working on use Ejb remote call and Value object pattern to encapsulate the data . Some Vo make controls on the data they contains. As we are migrating to web service we have to deal with this problem .

Answer (score 0):

Why not provide this class (your VO) to the client so both the server and client are marshalling/unmarshalling the same class? Then both can use the your method...

Comment: That's what I'm doing . I wanted to be sure that there is no other way to do it.

Comment: I think thats good advice, BUT are you opening up the web services to other callers/clients? If so, remember you will have to cope with web service calls from other clients which are not using your VO classes. So, for example, just because your standard client runs a VO validation method every time, the server cant assume that. The server must cope with invalid XML, incomplete XML, incorrect values, etc etc. soapUI testing is a good idea IME.

Answer (score -1):

> Marshalling" refers to the process of converting the data or the objects into a byte-stream, and "unmarshalling" is the reverse process of converting the byte-stream back into their original data or object.
>   The conversion is achieved through "serialization".
>
> The purpose of the "marshalling/unmarshalling" process is to transfer data between the RMI systems.

For more http://ws.apache.org/old/jaxme/manual/ch02s02.html